# Unable to import babel-plugins/presets in production for transform

Tags: reactjs, meteor, babeljs

I am using babel in production to transform jsx strings into html, for the purpose of rendering email bodies via string templates.

```
import {transform} from '@babel/core';
const {code} = transform(template, {plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx']});
```

I have `@babel/core` and `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` in my dependencies. The code works on development but on production it fails saying, 'Can not find module `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`'. Can someone help me debug/understand the underlying issue here?

I tried adding a deliberate `import '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx';` but to no avail.

Sample code for the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-euler-v21z3

Can it be a deployment issue? The complete error logs:

```
Exception while invoking method 'template.getComponentFunctions' Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx' from '/built_app/programs/server'
[13.127.129.224]    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:58:15)
[13.127.129.224]    at resolveStandardizedName (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
[13.127.129.224]    at resolvePlugin (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:54:10)
[13.127.129.224]    at loadPlugin (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:62:20)
[13.127.129.224]    at createDescriptor (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
[13.127.129.224]    at /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50
[13.127.129.224]    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
[13.127.129.224]    at createDescriptors (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
[13.127.129.224]    at createPluginDescriptors (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:105:10)
[13.127.129.224]    at /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:63:53
[13.127.129.224]    at cachedFunction (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:62:27)
[13.127.129.224]    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
[13.127.129.224]    at evaluateSync (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/gensync/index.js:244:28)
[13.127.129.224]    at sync (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/gensync/index.js:84:14)
[13.127.129.224]    at plugins (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:28:77)
[13.127.129.224]    at mergeChainOpts (/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:319:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was unable to figure out the reason and solve it properly, I was able to work around by using `@babel/standalone`.